# Why does my ExecuteNonQuery() return 0 in C#

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, executenonquery

I'm trying to update player records with a new TeamID but it's not updating, Any hints please

Comment: Are you sure that the PersonID exists?

Comment: You never update the parameters for the Update command.  You set them once at the start - changing the variable `Player_ID` doesn't change the value in the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. There is no Person_ID with value 0 in your database.

It looks like you might want to move a large portion of your code inside your while loop, like most of this

```
SqlCommand Updatecmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Persons SET TeamID=@Team_ID WHERE PersonID=@Person_ID", UpdateCon);
Updatecmd.Parameters.Add("@Team_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Updatecmd.Parameters.Add("@Person_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Updatecmd.Parameters["@Team_ID"].Value = PlayerTeam_ID;
Updatecmd.Parameters["@Person_ID"].Value = Player_ID;
```

Should be put after this

```
 PlayersCount++;
 Division_ID=reader.GetInt32(1);
 Player_ID = reader.GetInt32(0); 
 PlayerTeam_ID = PlayersCount % 4 + 4 * Division_ID;
```

Comment: What is that constraint?

Comment: Does the team id you're trying to update to exist in Teams? You'd need to provide a bunch more information for me to be able to help with this one.

Comment: @Fruits - It might be an order of operation issue.  `+` is evaluated before `%` and `*` (just like regular math).  You might be expecting your code to do modulus on PlayersCount, add 4 and then multiply by Division_ID, but what really happens is 4 is added to 4, and then PlayersCount is modulus 8, multiplied by DivisionID. IF you expected straight left to right, you can use parentheses: `(PlayersCount % 4) + 4 * Division_ID`.  What are the values you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

These two lines:

```
Updatecmd.Parameters["@Team_ID"].Value = PlayerTeam_ID;
Updatecmd.Parameters["@Person_ID"].Value = Player_ID;
```

Set the value initially to the variables `PlayerTeam_ID` and `Player_ID`.  In your `read` loop, you're updating the variables `PlayerTeam_ID` and `Player_ID`, but you're not updating the values in the parameters.  You should update the value of the parameters, like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    PlayersCount++;
    Division_ID=reader.GetInt32(1);
    Player_ID = reader.GetInt32(0); 
    PlayerTeam_ID = PlayersCount % 4 + 4 * Division_ID;

    Updatecmd.Parameters["@Team_ID"].Value = PlayerTeam_ID;
    Updatecmd.Parameters["@Person_ID"].Value = Player_ID;

    UpdateCon.Open();
    int intQuery = Updatecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ltlOutput.Text = intQuery.ToString();

    UpdateCon.Close();
}
```